# Script to copy database to existing database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Using Azure Portal, I have copied existing production database to a new staging database.

Now, I need to copy DB Schema and Data from Production to Staging periodically. 
I wand to avoid deleting the Staging database, because I want to keep settings like Pricing Tier, backup settings etc.

**How to I sync DB Schema and Data from one database to already another already existing database?**

Comment: Visual studio has database compare tool which can do this.

Comment: The tool Ben mentioned is SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?toc=/azure/sql-database/toc.json) and automating its execution using [Azure Automation](https://khangtran.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/automation-with-azure-data-factory-adf/).

Comment: Wrong product, does not solve the problem This is more an ETL tool, not usable for development where the schamata may change quite rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to copy DB Schema and Data from Production to Staging periodically

No, you do not. Not until you want to limit yourself to EXTREMELY basic changes and never rafactor anything.

Because schema changes can not copy data.

Simple schema sync SSDT can do.

But what you IMHO actually need is a concept of running change scripts. Because:

- Not all changes are trivial. I have been doing change copying data to temporatry tables and then moving them to a new table structure.
- You may not keep 2 databases. my main probject now has 9 (!) active development database PLUS possibly one or two per developer who want it. Changes are automatically deployed from the build server. And once you get real you will have pretty much a minimum of 4:

  - Production
  - End user testing
  - Development
  - Integration testing. Because this can run longer (our integration tests run around 4 hours) we can not that on development.

You need something that scales.

Also:

> I wand to avoid deleting the Staging database, because I want to keep settings like 
>   Pricing Tier, backup settings

I do not really get that. Azure is FULLY SCRIPTABLE. infrastructure as code. I.e. you could/should have a script initializing the copied database to defined settings.

Comment: We have CI/CD in place, we just don't have ARM templates or script to create the infrastructure or anything like that. Even then, ARM templates would not help me with copying production data to staging env.